# TikZ label do not display correctly anymore?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I upgraded my MiKTeX from 2.8 to 2.9 today. When I run my old code in this new system, I find it do not work well. `label=90:$A$` and `label=0+90:$A$` are displayed in two very differently ways! They were the same yesterday! This is just a stupid example, I want to write a `\foreach` sentence, such that the angles is a function. (Thanks for Hendrik Vogt)

```
\documentclass{article}% PDFLatex 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill,label=90:$A$] at (0,0) (P0){};
\node[fill,label=-90:$A$] at (2,0) (P1){};
\node[fill,label=45:$A$] at (4,0) (P2){};
\node[fill,label=-45:$A$] at (6,0) (P3){};
\node[fill,label=0+90:$A$] at (0,2) (P4){};
\node[fill,label=0-90:$A$] at (2,2) (P5){}; 
\node[fill,label=0+45:$A$] at (4,2) (P6){};
\node[fill,label=0-45:$A$] at (6,2) (P7){};
\node[fill,label={45+45}:$A$] at (8,2) (P8){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also mark the code and click the 'code' button (101010).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a pgf version problem.

- I can confirm this problem testing your example with pgf/TikZ 2.0.
- It works fine with pgf/TikZ 2.10: the labels are displayed in the same way.

So I recommend to upgrade pgf to the current version 2.10.

Since the problem did not occur with MiKTeX 2.8 for you, I'm sure you already used pgf 2.10 with MiKTeX 2.8 but the upgrade of the distribition to 2.9 installed the older version 2.0 of pgf. Run the MiKTeX package manager for updating your pgf package.